# Entity Framework Database First not bringing in functions

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-4

Im using vs2012 and have a project where I have an Entity Framework v4.4 model pointed at a Sql Server 2008R2 database. For a while I have been adding stored procs and functions to the database and using Update Model From Database to bring them into the model without any problems.

Recently another developer working on the project started having trouble adding new stored procs and functions - he is using VS2013. When he chooses Update Model From Database, new stored procs show up in the list of procs to add, but when Finish is pressed, they are not added to the model, and in fact if he chooses Update Model From Database again, they are still listed in the new stored procs to add. Same thing happens with new functions.

He was able to get around this by modifying the edmx file manually, but we don't like this solution.

We have looked on SO and seen messages regarding giving EXECUTE permission on the procs (which we have not had to do before this). We tried giving the Execute permission, but that didn't change anything - same behavior.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions were all table based functions, which evidently are not imported in EF 4